# gulp-minify without rename original files

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-minify

It is possible minify js files without add -min suffix?

I want keep original name.

```
gulp.task("js-external-release", function() {
    gulp.src(config.vendorJs)
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + "/scripts"));
});
```

Comment: What's the actual package name?  `gulp-uglify` does not rename js files.

Comment: I used gulp-minify but I changed to gulp-uglify. You are right, gulp-uglify doesn’t rename files.

Comment: Ok, I'll make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`gulp-uglify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) instead - it doesn't rename files, which is the default behavior for most gulp plugins.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task("js-external-release", function() {
    gulp.src(config.vendorJs)
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + "/scripts"));
});
```

Alternatively, you could use [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename), but switching to `uglify` will eliminate the need for such a plugin and is less complex than adding a new plugin in my opinion.

Comment: import should say `var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");`

Comment: glup-uglify is not supported anymore.

Answer (score 15):

This is a very old question, but it still pops up quite high on Google, and since Uglify is no longer actively maintained for ES6+ and `gulp-minify` is, I thought I’d add that it is (now) perfectly possible to do this with `gulp-minify`.

If you specify the extension of minified files to be just `.js` (or whatever your input file extension is) in your `gulp-minify` options, the minified file will have the same file name as the original. The problem is that `gulp-minify` by default also compiles a non-minified copy of the input file to the output directory – and that non-minified copy gets added *after* the minified copy, thus overwriting it and leaving you with just a copy of the original.

To get around this, set the `noSource` option to true – then no copy of the input file is output:

```js
gulp.task("js-external-release", function() {
    gulp.src(config.vendorJs)
    .pipe(minify({
        ext: {
            min: '.js' // Set the file extension for minified files to just .js
        },
        noSource: true // Don’t output a copy of the source file
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + '/scripts'));
});
```

Comment: This answer should be higher, especially as more people are using ES6+ (exact reason why I moved to gulp-minify over uglify). This solved the issue I was experiencing. Thank you!