# Gulp minification to same file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-minify

I am working in node js application. I want to minify server js files. Am using gulp for that purpose.

```
var folders = ['business','config','controllers','model','routes','utilities']

gulp.task('minify', function() {
    for(i=0;i<folders.length;i++){
        gulp.src(folders[i]+'/*.js')
            .pipe(rename({suffix: ""}))
            .pipe(minify({ext:'.js'}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(folders[i]))

    }
});
```

This is my gulp file. I need to minify the files in the folder without renaming or recreating any new file. But now it is creating in different folder and files will be appended with min suffix.

Is there any way to resolve this in gulp.

Comment: `minify` comes from what package?

Comment: var minify = require('gulp-minify');

Comment: For the filename the issue seems to be gulp-minify. Take a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881413/gulp-minify-without-rename-original-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this with both `gulp-minify` and `gulp-uglify`. `gulp-minify` seems to be adding that suffix willingly.

You can use `gulp-uglify` instead which worked for me:

```
gulp.src(folders[i]+'/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(folders[i]))
```